# Where do the singers sing on the Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade route?

Tags: new-york-city, thanksgiving

I saw the parade this year, close to the Diamond District, and the performers were just waving— they weren't signing. This kinda makes me wonder: where do they sing? Do they sing in one spot or multiple spots? And in either case, where are those spots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performances take place at the Official Viewing area, which is along 34th St at the end of the parade route.  It is where the TV camera crews set up, the VIPs hang out and is so crowded you are better off watching the performances later on your TV.